# Loop over array, not returning desired results

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, foreach

I'm using the following foreach loop to build a grid in a table of points from a racing series.

I was using a while loop with php mysql interface, but I have changed the entire site to us PDO, and this is the last part I need to get working. I'm really struggling with it.

The problem I am having is that it misses some data, doesn't display it on the page and the elseif does nothing. I don't get the blank cells. I need them so that it will pad the table to the right amount of columns so that the table doesn't look hideous.

Also just noticed that it's simply outputting wrong data.

This foreach happens inside of another foreach where I am matching the current line "schedule_id" with an array of "schedule_ids" from the race schedule. in that loop I'm doing a query to find the current rider

```
foreach ($results as $data) {
    var_dump($data);
    if ($data['schedule_id'] == $schedule) {
        if ($data['finish'] == "1") {
            echo "<td><strong>" . $data['finish'] . "</strong></td>\n<td><strong>" . $data['points'] . "</strong></td>\n";
        } else {
            echo "<td>" . $data['finish'] . "</td>\n<td>" . $data['points'] . "</td>\n";
        }
     } elseif ($data['points'] == "0") {
        echo "<td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>\n\n";
    }
}
```

The $data array looks like this:

```
array (size=5)
 'schedule_id' => int 27
 'finish' => int 1
 'points' => int 20
 'class_id' => int 1
 'rider_id' => int 1
array (size=5)
 'schedule_id' => int 43
 'finish' => int 3
 'points' => int 13
 'class_id' => int 1
 'rider_id' => int 1
array (size=5)
 'schedule_id' => int 27
 'finish' => int 3
 'points' => int 13
 'class_id' => int 1
 'rider_id' => int 3
array (size=5)
 'schedule_id' => int 43
 'finish' => int 2
 'points' => int 16
 'class_id' => int 1
 'rider_id' => int 3
array (size=5)
 'schedule_id' => int 43
 'finish' => int 4
 'points' => int 11
 'class_id' => int 1
 'rider_id' => int 129
```

Here is the complete code that produces this table. Any help getting this sorted out would be greatly appreciated.

```
$season_id = 3;


$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id, date FROM schedule WHERE raceevent = '1' AND cancelled = '0' AND season_id = :season_id ORDER BY date");
$stmt->execute(array(':season_id'=>$season_id));
$num_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
$numrows = ($num_rows * 2 + 5);


                           //display first blank cells of table
echo "<tr><th colspan=\"2\" rowspan=\"2\">&nbsp;</th>\n";

while ($r = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $date =  date_create($r['date']);
    $schedule_id_array[] = $r['id'];

                            //display the schedule dates for active races in the season
    echo  "<th colspan=\"2\" align=\"center\">" . date_format($date, 'm-d') . "</th>\n";

}
                            //display final two columns in table head
echo "<th rowspan=\"2\">Total<br>Points</th><th rowspan=\"2\">% entered</th></tr>";
echo "<tr>";

                            //display second row of table head
for ($i=1; $i<=$num_rows; $i++) {
    echo "<th>FIN</th><th>PTS</th>\n";
}
                            //close table head
echo "</tr></thead><tbody>\n";

                            //get rider classes
$stmt1 = $db->prepare("SELECT id, class FROM classes");
$stmt1->execute();
while ($r1 = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                            //get each rider in each class
    $stmt2 = $db->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT SUM(results.points) AS points, results.class_id, results.rider_id FROM results WHERE results.class_id = :id AND season_id = :season_id GROUP BY results.class_id, results.rider_id ORDER BY points DESC");
    $stmt2->execute(array(':id'=>$r1['id'], ':season_id'=>$season_id));
    while ($r2 = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                            //display classes and riders in each cleass
        echo "<tr><td>" . $r2['class_id'] . " - " . $f->getClassName($db, $r2['class_id']) ."</td>\n<td>" . $r2['rider_id'] . " - " . $f->getRiderName($db, $r2['rider_id']) . "</td>\n";

                            //loop thru the scheduled races         
        foreach($schedule_id_array as $schedule) {
                            //get points for each rider in each class unless the points for that rider = 0
        $stmt3 = $db->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT `schedule_id`, `finish`, `points`, `class_id`, `rider_id` FROM results WHERE schedule_id = :schedule and `rider_id` = :rider_id AND `class_id` = :class_id AND  `season_id` = :season_id ORDER BY schedule_id");
        $stmt3->execute(array(':schedule'=>$schedule,':rider_id'=>$r2['rider_id'], ':class_id'=>$r1['id'], ':season_id'=>$season_id));

            $results = $stmt3->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                            //loop thru each rider and display points for each schedule race                
            foreach ($results as $data) {

                var_dump($results);

                if ($data['schedule_id'] == $schedule) {

                    if ($data['finish'] = 1) {
                        echo "<td><strong>" . $data['rider_id'] . " - " . $data['finish'] . "</strong></td>\n<td><strong>" . $data['rider_id'] . " - "  . $data['points'] . "</strong></td>\n";
                    } else {
                        echo "<td>" . $data['rider_id'] . " - "  . $data['finish'] . "</td>\n<td>" . $data['rider_id'] . " - "  . $data['points'] . "</td>\n";
                    }

                } elseif ($data['points'] = 0) {
                    echo "<td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>\n\n";
                }

            }


        }

                            // end foreach schedule_id_array; print out total points and percent ran
        $stmt4 = $db->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT `schedule_id`, `finish`, `points` FROM results WHERE `rider_id` = :rider_id AND `class_id` = :id and `season_id` = :season_id");
        $stmt4->execute(array(':rider_id'=>$r2['rider_id'], ':id'=>$r1['id'], ':season_id'=>$season_id));
        $races = $stmt4->rowCount();
        $percent_races = ($races/$num_rows) * 100;
        echo "<td>" .  $r2['points'] . "</td><td>";
        printf("%.0f", $percent_races);
        echo "&#37;</td>";

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any closing TR `</tr>` tag in your loop.

Comment: thanks.. missed that.. that doesn't make the missing data show up, but formatting should be better.

Comment: What is `$schedule`? I suppose that condition fails. And you're checking if a int is equal to a string. PHP can handle this but it isn't very elegant.

Comment: foreach($schedule_id_array as $schedule)

When I test the INT as INT, it fails miserably still.. 

http://home.quickinet.net/midam/results-PDO.php

Comment: Is it normal that you have duplicated the `elseif ($data['points'] == "0")` condition ? Didn't make a lot of sense, maybe your problem is here.

Comment: Yes, that's no normal. It was just a lazy mistake, that should just be an else. the first echo shows the data in bold, this shows data that doesn't meet the criteria of the if statement not bolded. Thanks.
Code above has been updated.

Comment: Your indent is all messed up, hard to see what block these elseifs are part of.

Comment: I edited the code on here to make it a bit easier, and removed the first elseif from the code snip. It was not supposed to be there to begin with.

Comment: This problem could become simpler to solve if you split the markup generation apart from the data retrieval.

Comment: @quickshiftin I agree, but frankly I haven't found a good way to do that and get the output I need.

Comment: Lol, put the data from the queries into arrays and loop over them... You can barely tell what's going on the way the code reads currently.

Comment: @quickshiftin not sure how I can do that when some of the queries depend on data from earlier queries. I thought about sub queries or joins, but that hasn't worked in this case. Definitely open to a new way of doing things, but so far just haven't found a good way to make this work without busting something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still pretty ugly, but here is a stab in the right direction cleaning up the code... Once you get the code cleaned up it should become more obvious where your problem is.

As to your actual question, I sure hope this cleanup effort helps you track it down!

```
$season_id = 3;

// Fetch schedules
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id, date FROM schedule WHERE raceevent = '1' AND cancelled = '0' AND season_id = :season_id ORDER BY date");
$stmt->execute(array(':season_id'=>$season_id));
$iNumSchedules = $stmt->rowCount();

$aSchedules = array();
while($r = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    $aSchedules[$r['id']] = date_create($r['date']);

// Fetch classes
$stmt1 = $db->prepare("SELECT id, class FROM classes");
$stmt1->execute();
$aClasses = array();
while($r = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    $aClasses[$r['id']] = $r['class'];

function get_class_results($iClassId, $iSeasonId) {
    global $db;
    $stmt2 = $db->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT SUM(results.points) AS points, results.class_id, results.rider_id FROM results WHERE results.class_id = :id AND season_id = :season_id GROUP BY results.class_id, results.rider_id ORDER BY points DESC");
    $stmt2->execute(array(':id'=>$iClassId, ':season_id'=>$iSeasonId));
    $aClassResults = array();
    while($r = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        $aClassResults[] = $r;
    return $aClassResults;
}

function get_schedule_results($sSchedule, $iRiderId, $iClassId, $iSeasonId) {
    global $db;
    $stmt3 = $db->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT `schedule_id`, `finish`, `points`, `class_id`, `rider_id` FROM results WHERE schedule_id = :schedule and `rider_id` = :rider_id AND `class_id` = :class_id AND  `season_id` = :season_id ORDER BY schedule_id");
    $stmt3->execute(array(':schedule'=>$sSchedule,':rider_id'=>$iRiderId, ':class_id'=>$iClassId, ':season_id'=>$iSeasonId));
    return = $stmt3->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

function get_races($iRiderId, $iClassId, $iSeasonId) {
    global $db;
    $stmt4 = $db->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT `schedule_id`, `finish`, `points` FROM results WHERE `rider_id` = :rider_id AND `class_id` = :id and `season_id` = :season_id");
    $stmt4->execute(array(':rider_id'=>$iRiderId, ':id'=>$iClassId, ':season_id'=>$iSeasonId));
    return $stmt4->rowCount();
}

//------------------------------------------------------------
// Build the table header row
//------------------------------------------------------------
// display first blank cells of table
echo "<tr><th colspan=\"2\" rowspan=\"2\">&nbsp;</th>\n";

// display the schedule dates for active races in the season
foreach($aSchedules as $iScheduleId => $date)
    echo  "<th colspan=\"2\" align=\"center\">" . date_format($date, 'm-d') . "</th>\n";

// display final two columns in table head
echo "<th rowspan=\"2\">Total<br>Points</th><th rowspan=\"2\">% entered</th></tr>";
echo "<tr>";

// display second row of table head
for($i=1; $i<=$iNumSchedules; $i++) {
    echo "<th>FIN</th><th>PTS</th>\n";
}
// close table head
echo "</tr></thead><tbody>\n";

// get rider classes
foreach($aClasses as $iClassId => $sClassName) {

    // get each rider in each class
    foreach(get_class_results($iClassId, $season_id) as $r2) {

        // display classes and riders in each cleass
        echo "<tr><td>" . $r2['class_id'] . " - " . $f->getClassName($db, $r2['class_id']) ."</td>\n<td>" . $r2['rider_id'] . " - " . $f->getRiderName($db, $r2['rider_id']) . "</td>\n";

        // loop thru the scheduled races         
        foreach(array_keys($aSchedules) as $schedule) {
            $results = get_schedule_results($schedule, $r2['rider_id'], $iClassId, $season_id);

            // loop thru each rider and display points for each schedule race                
            foreach($results as $data) {

                if($data['schedule_id'] == $schedule) {

                    if($data['finish'] = 1)
                        echo "<td><strong>" . $data['rider_id'] . " - " . $data['finish'] . "</strong></td>\n<td><strong>" . $data['rider_id'] . " - "  . $data['points'] . "</strong></td>\n";
                    else
                        echo "<td>" . $data['rider_id'] . " - "  . $data['finish'] . "</td>\n<td>" . $data['rider_id'] . " - "  . $data['points'] . "</td>\n";

                } elseif($data['points'] = 0)
                    echo "<td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>\n\n";

            }
        }

        // end foreach schedule_id_array; print out total points and percent ran
        $races = get_races($r2['rider_id'], $iClassId, $season_id);
        $percent_races = ($races/$iNumSchedules) * 100;
        echo "<td>" .  $r2['points'] . "</td><td>";
        printf("%.0f", $percent_races);
        echo "&#37;</td>";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the result I get.. choking on this line:

    foreach(get_class_results($iClassId, $season_id as $r2))

( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS) in E:\Box Sync\Websites\midam\results-test.php on line 173

Comment: Lol, I didn't test it man.., I spent like 20 minutes cleaning up what you started with. Hoping you can tighten it up beyond that, and learn from the changes I made ...

Comment: `foreach(get_class_results($iClassId, $season_id) as $r2) {` Changed in the answer as well...

Comment: I do appreciate the code clean up. What I am not understanding in this is that in the $data array in the last foreach I can see `'points' => int 0` but the elseif isn't inserting the blank table cell like it should. And I can't see a reason why. it should work..

Comment: The last elseif isn't even getting evaluated.. The logic is bad. The very same logic worked well under the old style. Not sure why it would fail now.

Comment: This fixed it, but I had to add a couple of things to fill out the table with blanks. I'll post the rest of the code that made it work..

Answer (score 1):

```
$season_id = 3;

// Fetch schedules
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id, date FROM schedule WHERE raceevent = '1' AND cancelled = '0' AND season_id = :season_id ORDER BY date");
$stmt->execute(array(':season_id'=>$season_id));
$iNumSchedules = $stmt->rowCount();

$aSchedules = array();
while($r = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    $aSchedules[$r['id']] = date_create($r['date']);

// Fetch classes
$stmt1 = $db->prepare("SELECT id, class FROM classes");
$stmt1->execute();
$aClasses = array();
while($r = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    $aClasses[$r['id']] = $r['class'];

function get_class_results($iClassId, $iSeasonId) {
    global $db;
    $stmt2 = $db->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT SUM(results.points) AS points, results.class_id, results.rider_id FROM results WHERE results.class_id = :id AND season_id = :season_id GROUP BY results.class_id, results.rider_id ORDER BY points DESC");
    $stmt2->execute(array(':id'=>$iClassId, ':season_id'=>$iSeasonId));
    $aClassResults = array();
    while($r = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        $aClassResults[] = $r;
    return $aClassResults;
}

function get_schedule_results($sSchedule, $iRiderId, $iClassId, $iSeasonId) {
    global $db;
    $stmt3 = $db->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT `schedule_id`, `finish`, `points`, `class_id`, `rider_id` FROM results WHERE schedule_id = :schedule and `rider_id` = :rider_id AND `class_id` = :class_id AND  `season_id` = :season_id ORDER BY schedule_id");
    $stmt3->execute(array(':schedule'=>$sSchedule,':rider_id'=>$iRiderId, ':class_id'=>$iClassId, ':season_id'=>$iSeasonId));
    return  $stmt3->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

function get_races($iRiderId, $iClassId, $iSeasonId) {
    global $db;
    $stmt4 = $db->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT `schedule_id`, `finish`, `points` FROM results WHERE `rider_id` = :rider_id AND `class_id` = :id and `season_id` = :season_id");
    $stmt4->execute(array(':rider_id'=>$iRiderId, ':id'=>$iClassId, ':season_id'=>$iSeasonId));
    return $stmt4->rowCount();
}

//------------------------------------------------------------
// Build the table header row
//------------------------------------------------------------
// display first blank cells of table
echo "<tr><th colspan=\"2\" rowspan=\"2\">&nbsp;</th>\n";

// display the schedule dates for active races in the season
foreach($aSchedules as $iScheduleId => $date)
    echo  "<th colspan=\"2\" align=\"center\">" . date_format($date, 'm-d') . "</th>\n";

// display final two columns in table head
echo "<th rowspan=\"2\">Total<br>Points</th><th rowspan=\"2\">% entered</th></tr>";
echo "<tr>";

// display second row of table head
for($i=1; $i<=$iNumSchedules; $i++) {
    echo "<th>FIN</th><th>PTS</th>\n";
}
// close table head
echo "</tr></thead><tbody>\n";

// get rider classes
foreach($aClasses as $iClassId => $sClassName) {

    // get each rider in each class
    foreach(get_class_results($iClassId, $season_id) as $r2) {

        // display classes and riders in each cleass
        echo "<tr><td>" . $f->getClassName($db, $r2['class_id']) ."</td>\n<td>" . $r2['rider_id'] . " - " . $f->getRiderName($db, $r2['rider_id']) . "</td>\n";

        // loop thru the scheduled races         
        foreach(array_keys($aSchedules) as $schedule) {
            $schedule_ids_matched = FALSE; // ADDED THIS TO FIX THE BLANKS
            $results = get_schedule_results($schedule, $r2['rider_id'], $iClassId, $season_id);

            // loop thru each rider and display points for each schedule race                
            foreach($results as $data) {

                 if($data['schedule_id'] == $schedule) {
            $schedule_ids_matched = TRUE; // ADDED THIS TO FIX THE BLANKS
                    if($data['finish'] == 1)
                        echo "<td><strong>" . $data['finish'] . "</strong></td>\n<td><strong>"  . $data['points'] . "</strong></td>\n";
                    else
                        echo "<td>"  . $data['finish'] . "</td>\n<td>"  . $data['points'] . "</td>\n";

                }
        }
    if (!$schedule_ids_matched)// ADDED THIS TO FIX THE BLANKS
            echo "<td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>\n\n";
        }
        // end foreach schedule_id_array; print out total points and percent ran
        $races = get_races($r2['rider_id'], $iClassId, $season_id);
        $percent_races = ($races/$iNumSchedules) * 100;
        echo "<td>" .  $r2['points'] . "</td><td>";
        printf("%.0f", $percent_races);
        echo "&#37;</td>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help on this.. I was feeling rather lost on the whole thing. Sometimes you just need to be nudged in the right direction.

Comment: @quickshiftin, Hey, wonder if I can get you to have a look at another issue similar to this that I am having. I'm hopelessly stuck.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34457101/looping-with-a-query-and-lookup-table-mysql-php